# terminal in vscode lost history after update

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have setted up vscode to run zsh as default. Yesterday I ran an update in vscode yesterday and since then I've lost the history.

It seems that it opens its own instance.

```
echo $HISTFILE

/var/folders/79/yxms393s2510hr4cnmzj5z1m0000gn/T/nikos-code-zsh/.zsh_history
```

Any ideas on how I could revert that change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported to the vscode repository and a fix was created already. It's available in the insiders release and to the standard release today.

> [#168396](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168396)
>
> already fixed in insider's and soon to be fixed in our recovery release (tomorrow)